# Delete the rows with same entires corresponding to specific groups in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataset:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd


#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7,7,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   4, 4, 4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                   8, 8, 8, 8,8,8,8,8,9,10,11,12,13],
        'Children': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes'],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 120, 141,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,128, 66, 120, 141,
                 120, 141,123,15,85,36,58,89,123, 128, 66, 120, 141],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataset looks as such:

[image]

I wish to delete the rows with same entries from 'Salary' with respect to specific group/id.

For example,

For id = 1, delete rows with 'Salary'=7, except the last entry.

For id = 2, delete rows with 'Salary'=4, except the last entry.

For id = 3, delete rows with 'Salary'=8, except the last entry.

The new dataset should look as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know hot to achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` and `|` for bitwise `OR` with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
mask = ((df['id'].ne(1) & df['Salary'].ne(7) &
         df['id'].ne(2) & df['Salary'].ne(4) &
         df['id'].ne(3) & df['Salary'].ne(8)) | 
         ~df.duplicated(['id','Salary'], keep='last'))

df = df[mask]
print("df = \n", df)
     id  Salary Children  Days
6    1       7      Yes   128
7    1       8      Yes    66
8    1       9      Yes   120
9    1      10       No   141
10   1      11       No    52
11   1      12      Yes    96
12   1      13      Yes   120
13   1      14      Yes   141
14   1      15       No    52
18   2       4      Yes   141
19   2       5      Yes    52
20   2       6      Yes    96
21   2       7      Yes   128
22   2       8      Yes    66
23   2       9      Yes   120
24   2      10       No   141
32   3       8       No    89
33   3       9      Yes   123
34   3      10      Yes   128
35   3      11       No    66
36   3      12       No   120
37   3      13      Yes   141
```

EDIT: If need only removed all duplicates with keep last rows per `id,Salary` columns use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) :

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','Salary'], keep='last')
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @NN_Developer - So need `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','Salary'], keep='last')` ?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael..."df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','Salary'], keep='last')" this is ok....Will apply this...

Answer (score 1):

try :  drop_duplicates()

`df = df.apply(lambdax:x.astype(str).str.lower()).drop_duplicates(subset='id','Salary'], keep='last')`

**new output**

df =

```
        id Salary Children Days
    6   1      7      yes  128
    7   1      8      yes   66
    8   1      9      yes  120
    9   1     10       no  141
    10  1     11       no   52
    11  1     12      yes   96
    12  1     13      yes  120
    13  1     14      yes  141
    14  1     15       no   52
    18  2      4      yes  141
    19  2      5      yes   52
    20  2      6      yes   96
    21  2      7      yes  128
    22  2      8      yes   66
    23  2      9      yes  120
    24  2     10       no  141
    32  3      8       no   89
    33  3      9      yes  123
    34  3     10      yes  128
    35  3     11       no   66
    36  3     12       no  120
    37  3     13      yes  141
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohit for your valuable suggestions....HOever this is would be the correct syntax...
df = df.apply(lambda x:x.astype(str).str.lower()).drop_duplicates(subset=['id','Salary'], keep='last')